# Unable to get image from site column in display template

Tags: display-template, content-search-web-part, image

I have a site column of type Publishing Image. I want to use it in my display template after mapping it to the crawled property. But it always returns null. I have mapped the column to a crawled property whose name is `ows_r_IMGE_ServiceIcon` but still unable to get the value of the image. Please help

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure the following actions are done.**

1. Managed property is created with Query, Search and Retrieve options as shown below.
2. Run the crawling (at least incremental) after creating the search managed property.

[image]

Comment: I have made the changes as per your advice @Murali but they are not working.

Comment: Validate the below scenarios:

1.Make sure it is crawled by searching the for the image name in Crawl Logs.
2.Make sure it is returned in OOTB search by search managedproperty:imagename. If you do not have the search site available you can do it at http://sitecollectionurl/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx

Also can you share the html line from display template?